# Does POSTing a file require a <form> tag and button?

Tags: javascript, file, post, input, file-upload

I have an option in the header in my webapp to select a file with `<input type='file'/>`, and I want as soon as the file is selected that it starts uploading it to my local nodejs server.

Do I need to encapsulate it in a  tag with POST attribute and and confirm it with a button? And/Or is it possible to call the POSTing immediately when the file is selected instead of using a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set a onchange event for the `<input type="file" id="input">` elm.

> Javascript

```
let input = document.getElementById('input');
input.onchange = function(e) { 
  if (file.files.length > 1) {
     // Upload
  }
};
```

After the form value for a selected file is present and our `onchange` event is triggered. We then post the file using a Fetch post.

> Example

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');

function upload(file) {
  fetch('http://', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'file-type'
    },
    body: file
  }).then(() => {

  }).catch((error) => {
    // Errors
    console.log('Log the error, since we are demoing');
  })
}

let chosen = () => {
    try {
       upload(input.files[0]);
    } catch(error) {

    }
}

input.addEventListener('change', chosen, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="input" />
```

Comment: @Sven0567 I put an example.